# how select a "next page" with Parsehub

Tags: parsehub

I cannot manage to create the good selector for the "next page" button in this page https://www.id2sante.fr/index.php?rub=annuaires

what is the Xpath (or CSS) command in Parsehub for selecting?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that sets off the arrow next button, but you can use CSS `span.select + a` to use the position of the blacked out link for the current page and find its next sibling instead.

For completeness, here's an XPath that would also work: `//a[text()=">"]`